# Why does a packaged Electron app fail due to Menu.getApplicationMenu() returning null while running it with electron . is fine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, menu, electron, packager

I get a strange error when running a packaged Electron app on Windows 10.
[image]

When I press Ok on this error, the application boots up, but without a menu. If I run the same application using `electron .` it works perfectly, it has a  menu.

The error occurs here:

```
var filemenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu().items[0].submenu;
filemenu.items[0].visible = false;
filemenu.append(new MenuItem({ label: 'Build Project', click: function () { buildProject(); } }));
```

I'm trying to edit the default File menu and add a "Build Project" item.

This is my first attempt to package an Electron app so I welcome any feedback as to what went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the default menu is not added to the app when in production.

The solution is to check if you are in development:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-is-dev

```
// Check if we are in development
var isDev = require('electron-is-dev');
```

If in production, you have to construct the menu from scratch.

```
if(isDev){
    // In development
    // modify existing menu
}else{
    // In production
    // construct menu from scratch
    var template = [
            {
                label: "File",
                submenu: [
                    {
                        label: "Exit",
                        click: function () { quit(); }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                label: "Project",
                submenu: [
                    {
                        label: "Delete",
                        click: function () { deleteProject(); }
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Build",
                        click: function () { buildProject(); }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];        
    // build menu from template
    var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);    
    // set menu for main window
    mainWindow.setMenu(menu);
};
```

Comment: i'm on electron v2 (old legacy app) and also was having problems with this. might be related to how they set the default menu https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/c4182752282db0b3c33750445802e2d65dad36db/lib/browser/default-menu.ts#L9